# UIWebView youtube iframe api autoplay/playsinline quit working in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

This code has worked really well to auto-play video inline in an iOS 6 uiwebview. However, I upgraded to iOS 7 and now my video will not auto-play. Sometimes video will auto-play and sometimes it won't. It will auto-play about 10% of the time. Most of the time I get a spinning wheel. If I remove &playsinline=1 from the src tag it will auto-play fullscreen (not what I want). I spent a lot of time creating a custom player for this app and now it won't work correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
_youTubeWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 184)];
_youTubeWebView.delegate = self;
_youTubeWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
_youTubeWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
_youTubeWebView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = YES;
_youTubeWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
[self.view addSubview:_youTubeWebView];

 NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){ a.target.playVideo(); }</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%@' height='%@'src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&controls=0&showinfo=0' frameborder='0'></body></html>", w, h, videoId];
 [_youTubeWebView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Here's a link to a quick test file. [videoPlayerTest.zip](http://s3.amazonaws.com/m21m-dev/videoPlayerTest.zip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like the following open bug against the Youtube iframe player API:

```
Issue 5204: js iframe api playVideo() doesn't play video in iOS 7
```

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5204

Comment: Thanks, I'm not loosing my mind. I can up vote yet or I'd up vote this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix the autoplay behavior by changing the baseURL to:

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get a spinning wheel about 90% of the time in iOS 7. I also noticed the youtube app has a lot of errors now in their videos. I have to double tap to get them to start.